# Is there a common word that encompasses handling of position, rotation, and scale together?

Tags: mathematics, matrix

I'm looking for a name for my class that manipulates 4x4 matrices that handle position, rotation, and scale. Is there a common word that encompasses all three?

(I'm splitting the matrix math into its own file/class.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

transform, or transformation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

Answer (score 8):

If you add shear to your list (although rarely used in games), it is generally known in mathematics as an [affine transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation).

The general term 'transformation' has been mentioned already, is a usually considered a superset and includes projection transformations as well (which are not affine).

Answer (score 1):

I've seen PRS used (position, rotation, scale), but "transformation matrix" is a pretty informative name, and also covers other kinds of transformations (skewing etc).

Answer (score 1):

I've seen several engines shorten the term to `Xform` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Some variant of `Transform` or `Transformation` would work.