# terminology: a position and a facing

Tags: terminology

my units have a function that returns a position (vec3) and a facing (quaternion) for any point in time.

A position and direction is perhaps called a *ray* or, in some contexts, a *line segment*; however, neither of these sounds appropriate in this context and neither normally has a quaternion...

What better name should a compound position and facing be called?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8266/is-there-a-common-word-that-encompasses-handling-of-position-rotation-and-scal

Comment: A distinction to make against the ray/line case is that while a ray has direction, it doesn't have an unique orientation.

Comment: @Tetrad yes I have the accepted answer on that linked question; I'd call it transform if I'd flattened it into a matrix.  I guess I can call 'pose' transform too...

Answer (score 6):

Well, the Robotics people call it [pose (position+orientation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pose_%28computer_vision%29).

Answer (score 3):

It's usually called a Transform (sometimes shortened to xForm). It also usually includes scale.